# GWT development mode on unix. How to run?

Tags: unix, gwt, ant

How can I run dev mode via ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about being able to interact with the DevMode UI, you could use `Xvfb :1` and define the `DISPLAY=:1` environment variable before running DevMode.

There's no support in the DevMode app for console-based output, although it does have a headless mode which sends log messages to the Google Eclipse Plugin.  You could probably build off of that to create a console-oriented version of the UI.